# TinyMCE Change language

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

Goodmoring,

Today i have installed TinyMCE on my custom made CMS. 
Now i want to change the language to dutch, my whole tinyMCE textbox will disappear.

I have uploaden the dutch files to the locations specified by TinyMCE. When i don't add the language : "nl", line to my TinyMCE javascript it will work (language is English). But when I add the line, the whole textbox disappear from my page.

This is my Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
            $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({

                // Location of TinyMCE script
                script_url : 'jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                // General options
                theme : "advanced",

                relative_urls : false,
                plugins : "youtubeIframe,jbimages,autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,images,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist,jbimages",

                // Theme options
                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "code,preview,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,|,insertdate,inserttime",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,youtubeIframe,jbimages,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",


                //COMPLETE LIJST VAN FUNCTIES
                //theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                //theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                //theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                //theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",



                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                theme_advanced_resizing : true,
                language : "nl",
                // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                content_css : "css/style.css",

                // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
                external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
                external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
                media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

                // Replace values for the template plugin
                template_replace_values : {
                    username : "Some User",
                    staffid : "991234",
                width : "858"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- /TinyMCE -->
```

I have tried to place the line in other places, but nothing helps.

Has anybody an idea to solve this problem, i really need the dutch language.

PS. I'm working with the jQuery version of TinyMCE

No I have tried to rename the nl file to en.js en changed the 2 letters inside of the file. But now nothing show up. The only thing I see now is as example print.print_desc instead of printing or print.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for Language support? http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Language

Comment: Yes, i did. But here they talk about tinyMCE.init({ but in my code (copied from the TinyMCE site) they use $().ready(function() {
            $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({. 

I dont know if this make sence?

Comment: Are you having your nl.js in the langs folder alongwith en.js

Comment: Yes, All the files are in the correct folders.

Comment: I've tried a things more to solve this solution, but it still doesn't work. Well i've noticed that when I use language : "en"; the textbox is vissible and TinyCME works well. I've downloaded the translation file from the original tinyCME site, and compared it by myself to the en.js file

Comment: do you get any js errors in your console/firebug

Answer (score 1):

1- download you langage's package from here : https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/language-packages/

2- Make sur to unzip the package in the path : `yourProject/public/assets/js/langs/yourLangagePack.js`
(add the folder if it not exists ...)

3- initialize tinyMce like that

```
 tinymce.init({
            selector: '#your_textArea_id',
            language: "fr_FR", // french for example ...
            // other options ...
            height: "1000"
        });
```

ps : write the langage abreviation like mentionned in the website bellow ( for example : `en` not `eng`, `fr_FR` not only `fr` )

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the language pack via tinyMCE.init like so:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.4");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "editor", 
    theme : "advanced",
    language : 'nl',
});
</script>

<textarea class="editor">
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

tinyMCE.init is defined in tiny_mce.js which comes bundled with the download in "tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce". As far as I know language packs can't be used in the jQuery version of tinyMCE.

Comment: tiny_mce.js does not have tinyMCE.init function.

Comment: @FatimaZohra In order to call the init function you will need to download the following version of tinyMCE: http://github.com/downloads/tinymce/tinymce/tinymce_3.5.7.zip